# Remove duplicates in an array based on a specific field

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in PHP like this:

`[{"pos"=0,"name"="Tom"},{"pos"=1,"name"="John"},{"pos"=2,"name"="Tom"}]`

I want to remove duplicates in this array based on "name". In other words, I want to get an array like this:

`[{"pos"=0,"name"="Tom"},{"pos"=1,"name"="John"}]`

How can we do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$unique = array();
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($v) use(&$unique){
    $inArray = in_array($v->name, $unique);
    if(!$inArray) $unique[] = $v->name;
    return !$inArray;
});
```

[**demo**](http://ideone.com/w3sxx9)